# MVC5 jQuery Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I have 2 pages in the same MVC5 application, the first page jqueryval works fine and on another it doesnt.  They are using 2 diferent _Layout pages but all the referenced scripts and styles are the same, unless I am blind.

This is the **Working** view

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Registration</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/dist/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Content/kendo/css?v=BRNdJQ-WO0tJDJizmw6veCLWmplb0_pVfAw25EB1cSo1" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/Scripts/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Braintree-->
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
    <script src="/bundles/kendo?v=8a-eVl9OWVi3D9bqkSvoiEAccYbkpGkrY2gmyFSb7zY1"></script>

</head>
<body>

... Removed for berevity.. can be added if needed

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="/Scripts/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="/Scripts/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="/Scripts/bower_components/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>


    <script src="/bundles/jqueryval?v=NOVQDySGO89wzMzO5x7mWS4C_uAdynpZe_Lk2y-xEM41"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have this second page where the jqueryval is **Not Working**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>New Appointment</title>
    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/dist/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/dist/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="/Content/bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/Content/kendo/css?v=BRNdJQ-WO0tJDJizmw6veCLWmplb0_pVfAw25EB1cSo1" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <link href="/Content/extras.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="/Content/extras.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="/Scripts/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--Braintree-->

    <script src="/bundles/kendo?v=8a-eVl9OWVi3D9bqkSvoiEAccYbkpGkrY2gmyFSb7zY1"></script>


</head>
<body>
... left out for berevity, but can be added if needed ...

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="/Scripts/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="/Scripts/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="/Scripts/bower_components/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>


    <script src="/bundles/jqueryval?v=NOVQDySGO89wzMzO5x7mWS4C_uAdynpZe_Lk2y-xEM41"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"2e5209e5c8fc4291a24966678450e237"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost:44399/394b2df3ceef431890edde525a8c014f/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried many different things to get his working and haven't figure out what the issue is.  Any help would be great.

**UPDATE**

You right I didnt really describe the issue i was rushing to meeting.  To describe what I showing the 2 pages are placement of the links and script references.  On the **working** view when i push the submit button the jquery validations fire and there is no post back because the form is not valid.  On the **not working** view i click the submit button the page does a full post back even when there are errors on the page.  No matter what I or the errors on the view the validations jquery validations never fire.

Comment: What is "not working"?  You're basically only showing us two lists of script includes.  If you've included all the proper files and there are no 404 errors, the problem is likely elsewhere.

Comment: I updated the OP, i am not getting any 404 or page errors, the simple error explanation is that jquery validations do not fire on the working page and that the jquery validations do fire on the working page.  I posted the page examples to see if there is problem that i am not seeing with liked scripts

Comment: Again, you've shown us nothing but the script includes.  If there are no 404 errors on those scripts, the problem must be elsewhere; so you need to **show us enough code that duplicates the issue**.

Comment: I dont know what other parts of the code to show, thats y I started with the scripts... I tried posting them and I run over the 30k character limit.  but i was posting the entire page.  As I have said I am not getting 404 errors.  I have telerik KendoUI combobox's on the page the make ajax calls to the underneath controller and a KendoUI calendar on the same view which does not fire the jqueryval's.  the working page also have a kendoUI combobox that is loaded by hardcoded values.

Comment: We certainly don't want the whole page posted either.  You'll have to figure out how to show us the relevant code.  Inspect the HTML & JavaScript as ***rendered*** by the browser.  Since we're trying to troubleshoot jQuery Validate, we'd only need to see the `.validate()` method, the HTML of the `<form>` and any other methods from the plugin you may have used.  Otherwise, without seeing the actual problematic code, I really don't know how we'll be able to help.

Comment: Well thats what i wanted to do in the beginning but it packaged in a bundle and doesnt actually render the forms validate script on the page.  If there is way for me to that, it would be great to know.

Comment: I know a lot about how to troubleshoot the jQuery Validate plugin.  Unfortunately, I know nothing about your packaged bundles.

Comment: well i fixed all but one view, I moved the @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
} to the same or outter div of where my form was and now all the views were it was not firing are now firing and except for one.  which is better then what i was getting before.  I also made sure it was above any script i wrote for that page.  but when i look at the page after it is rendered it still places it at the bottom as the layout suggests.  So Im confused to how that fixed all but one.